# A script to check if a java process is running as root user

Tags: command-line, scripts, java, root, process

I am currently trying to create a script to check if a specific java process ( `ps -efl | grep java` ) is running as root.

Currently I have come up with the following, but it hasn't printed what I need, any suggestions where I am going wrong?

```
process_count=`pgrep -u root -x Introscope_WebView.lax;echo $?`
if [ "$process_count" -eq 1]
    then
        process_user="Root"
    else
        process_user="Not Root"
fi
echo "<metric type=\"LongCounter\" name=\"OS Processes|WebView User Process:Process Count\" value=\"$process_count\"/>"
echo "<metric type=\"StringEvent\" name=\"OS Processes|WebView User Process:Process User\" value=\"$process_user\"/>"
exit 0
```

In this instance the java process will be *Introscope_WebView.lax* and I want to check if this is running as root user. If so give me 1 & running root otherwise give me else and not root.

Comment: The -x option of pgrep only matches processes that EXACTLY matches the pattern. Maybe the name is something else, try looking with 'ps -ef | grep "Introscope"*. Also, what are the EXACT output of youe pgrep command ? Try echoing it like 'echo "X${process_count}X" and check what's between the X's. Last, if the above works, what is the result if more than one Introscope process is running as root ?

Comment: Hi @SorenA - Thank you for your reply, yes I have checked the name and this is correct, its very strange .....................................  /opt/ca/APM/Introscope10.2.0.27/Introscope_WebView.lax /tmp/env.properties.12003
rp1cem   16238 14948  0 14:14 pts/0    00:00:00 grep java

Answer (score 4):

You should just be able to test the exit status of `pgrep` directly e.g.

```
if pgrep -u root -xf 'Introscope_WebView.lax' > /dev/null
then
    process_user="Root"
else
    process_user="Not Root"
fi
```

Note that this will also set `process_user="Not Root"` if the process does not exist at all - if you want to cover all three cases (running and owned by root; running but owned by someone else; not running) you will need to add a separate test.

---

e.g. given

```
$ ps -ef | grep [i]nit
root         1     0  0 Jan21 ?        00:00:05 /sbin/init splash
```

then

```
$ if pgrep -xfu root '/sbin/init splash' >/dev/null ; then echo 'root owns it'; fi
root owns it
```

---

From `man pgrep`

```
EXIT STATUS
       0      One or more processes matched the criteria.
       1      No processes matched.
       2      Syntax error in the command line.
       3      Fatal error: out of memory etc.
```

Comment: Thank you for your response - Tried using this but still says Not Root, when I check using ps -efl | grep java it states it is running as root: /opt/ca/APM/Introscope10.2.0.27/Introscope_WebView.lax /tmp/env.properties.12003

Comment: So how can 'Introscope_WebView.lax' be an exact match to '/opt/ca/APM/Introscope10.2.0.27/Introscope_WebView.lax' ?

Comment: You probably meant to use `-f`